# Passing prop to another component and render on the view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

```
import Form from './Form'
  class SideBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    item: '' 
  };
}
render() {
  return (
    this.props.products.map((x) => {
    let boundItemClick = this.onItemClick.bind(this, x);
    return <li key={x.id} onClick={boundItemClick}>{x.id}-{x.style_no}-{x.color}</li>

    }));
  }

  onItemClick= function(item, e) {  
    console.log(item)
  }
 }

export default SideBar
import SideBar from './SideBar'

class Form extends React.Component{
  render(){

  return();

}
}


 export default Form




**strong text**<div class = first_half><%= react_component("SideBar", {products: 
@products}) %></div>
<div class = second_half><%= react_component("Form", {products: 
@products}) %></div>
```

I have a question about how to pass the props to Form component. Right now, the SideBar component list all the link, and everything I click one of the link, I can console.log the information. But I have no idea how to pass it on the other component and render on the view. Thank you

for example : (this is a sidebar componenet)
301-abc
302-efg
303-rgk

When user click 301-abc, it will show coresponding details like id, color, and style.

Comment: what is the relation between "form" and "sidebar" is the form inside your sidebar or it's vice-versa?

Comment: you can imagine that there is two div left is a sidebar, and right is form. sidebar contain 100 <li>. Everytime use click one of the li will be prop the item to Form. So that it can render on the view (right div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got a lot of nested components which need to be aware of each other state/information, your best choice is to choose a state management something like [redux](https://redux.js.org/),[flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) or etc. state management mission is to hold data across components and helps you keep uni-direction data-flow in react.
Although, if you don't want to use a state management mechanism for any reason. you may implement it like this (which is ugly):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pkn3cu

Comment: Can you help me one more question.

Answer (score 1):

Likewise `SideBar` component you have to create constructor a `Form` component.

And you have to create **state** with **products** detail.

```
class SideBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      item: ''
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      this.props.products.map((x) => {
        let boundItemClick = this.onItemClick.bind(this, x);
        return <li key={x.id} onClick={boundItemClick}>{x.id} - {x.style_no} - {x.color}</li>
      }));
  }

  onItemClick = function(item, e) {
    console.log(item)
    this.props.selectedData(item);
  }
}
export default SideBar

import SideBar from './SideBar'

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      products: [{
        id: '302',
        style_no: 'abc',
        color: 'red'
      }, {
        id: '303',
        style_no: 'abcd',
        color: 'black'
      }],
      selectedData: {}
    };
  }

  getSelectedData(selectedData) {
    this.setState({
      selectedData: selectedData
    });
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <SideBar products = {this.state.products} selectedData={this.getSelectedData}>
    );
  }

}
```

In above code I have pass method as pops with name **`selectedData`** and you can use that in your **`onItemclick`** method as I used it and pass your item.

**this.props.selectedData(item);**

So, you will get that item in your `Form` component and set your state and you can display it in your `Form` component and can also pass to another component.

Hope it will work for you..!!

Comment: how can I prop the item from SideBar to Form    
 "onItemClick= function(item, e) {  
    console.log(item)
  }"
since item in the function contains all the information I need for render on view

Comment: okay. so you can pass the "method" to child component as a prop. it will use as a callback function in another component.

Comment: So, you want to pass your selected data to another component and render it ?

Comment: yes, can you show me about that. I have no idea how to do that

Comment: you can imagine that there is two div left is a sidebar, and right is form. sidebar contain 100 <li>. Everytime use click one of the li will be prop the item to Form. So that it can render on the view (right div)